# How to make my Outlook fallback not show for my embedded video in HTML email?

Tags: html, css, html-email, vml

I embedded a video in our email using HTML and the video works in some clients while the fallback shows in the other clients. My problem is that when I tested the html email in Litmus it showed that the fallback and the video appeared in Outlook MacOS 12.6.1 See screenshot below:
[Screenshot of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7yAc.png)

If I remove the fallback for Outlook, the video or image will not show up in Outlook browser.

I'd like to ask if there is a way I can target Outlook MacOs and Outlook browser? Maybe using vml? media query?

Thank you!

Please see my code below (I used example links and images as an example for now):

```
<!-- Video -->
 <tr>
    <td style="padding: 30px 30px 10px 30px;">
        <video class="video" width="540" controls poster="https://fakeimg.pl/540x400" src="https://example.com/yourvideoname.mp4">
    <!--your fallback goes here-->
    <a class=”video” rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com/" ><img style="width: 540px;" src="https://fakeimg.pl/540x400" width="540" /></a>
</video>
<!--outlook.com fallback-->
<a class="videoFallback" style="display: none; mso-hide: all;" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com/"><img border="0" src="https://fakeimg.pl/540x400" width="540"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- /Video -->
```

My styling includes:

```
 .video\0 { 
    display: none !important; 
}
.videoFallback\0 { 
    display: block !important; 
    
    }
```

Comment: See https://www.howtotarget.email/?q=outlook and https://www.caniemail.com/. It may be possible, but also the Outlooks are merging into Outlook.com as the core rendering engine so I'm not sure if this is possible anymore (does video work in Outlook mac anymore? that's a question to test. There has been changes to it recently)

Comment: Thank you!!! I'll go and search for that, I really haven't looked up the changes yet but I know that Outlook is merging to Outlook.com. I saw a solution for my problem which is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834948/macos-only-issue-hiding-html-email-for-office-365-outlook-2016 it worked and hid the other fallback on MacOs.